# Returning data from 3m back, or next available date

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a hist_tab that is updated daily and has contract, part, family, shortage_date, and qty.

I also have the below logic which works fine.  Basically for each part/product_family combination to list the qty as it was 3/6/12ms back:

```
select distinct contract, family, part,
case when trunc(shortage_date) = add_months(sysdate, -3) then qty end as part_short_3m,
case when trunc(shortage_date) = add_months(sysdate, -6) then qty end as part_short_6m,
case when trunc(shortage_date) = add_months(sysdate, -12) then qty end as part_short_12m
from hist_tab
```

The results for the 3/6/12m are null since there isn't data for exactly 3m ago.  But what I need is one step further, and by chance there isn't a qty with a date for exactly 3ms back, I need the qty for the next date back to be displayed. So for today example, no data record for 20-OCT-20, and next available qty is from 19-OCT-20, then I need to show the qty for 19-OCT-20.  I know I need to adjust the case statements to add an is null filter but I'm struggling with how to get that next date backs data to populate.

ETA data example and output expectation for just the 3m column:

```
Hist Tab entries:
con     part    fam    date        qty
1424F   T69P01  XC     23-NOV-20    151
1424F   T69P01  XC     19-OCT-20    228
1424F   T69P01  XC     12-OCT-20    190

Current Output:
con   fam   part    part_3m
1424F XC    T69P01  null

Expected Output:
con   fam   part    part_3m
1424F XC    T69P01  228
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results, perhaps for a simplified use-case?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I edited the post with some sample data just for 1 part and the 3m column.  I can figure the branching out from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation. First you need to refresh your memory of (or read for the first time about) the `first/last` aggregate function. In this case we will use the `last` function. The "conditional" part: you order by date, but you treat dates less than three months back as `null`, and you carefully specify that nulls should come **first** in the ordering, so that the "last" date is indeed the last date among those that are at least three months back.

The query below shows the results for the three-month period; you can add two more columns in the output, handling six- and twelve-month periods exactly the same way.

Note that `date` is a reserved keyword, so you can't use it as a column name (unless enclosed in double-quotes, which is unnecessary in this case); I changed the name to `date_`, with a trailing underscore. And, more importantly, you shouldn't use strings where you mean dates. I used date literals in the `with` clause (which you don't need - it's there just for testing; I am just assuming that your real-life data is stored, properly, in DATE data type, not as strings).

```
with
  hist_tab (con, part, fam, date_, qty) as (
    select '1424F', 'T69P01', 'XC', date '2020-11-23', 151 from dual union all
    select '1424F', 'T69P01', 'XC', date '2020-10-19', 228 from dual union all
    select '1424F', 'T69P01', 'XC', date '2020-10-12', 190 from dual
  )
select con, part, fam,
       min(qty) keep (dense_rank last 
                      order by case when date_ <= add_months(sysdate, -3)
                                    then date_ end nulls first) as qty_3m
from   hist_tab
group  by con, part, fam
;

CON    PART    FAM  QTY_3M
-----  ------  ---  ------
1424F  T69P01  XC      228
```

Link to documentation of `last` aggregate function:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions095.htm#SQLRF00653

**EDIT**  If you only need the three-month-back data, a more natural approach would be to simply filter out the rows with date within the past three months (in a `where` clause), and then still use the `last` function, but you wouldn't need the `case` expression within it. However, you must do this for three months back, six months back and twelve months back, and it is most efficient to do it all in a single query, so the approach I showed is probably best.

If you find that execution time becomes a problem, you may still filter out the rows with date within the past **three** months; other than that, you still need conditional `last` aggregate (at least for the six and twelve month periods), but at least the query won't have to work with rows that are guaranteed to be irrelevant - those within the last three months.

Comment: The approach you showed worked great, as I did need the 3/6/12m configurations as well.  I also am aware that `date` is a reserved keyword, I just used that term in my data and output example, but the real field being used is above shown as `shortage_date`.  I appreciate the documentation link also!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT contract,
       part,
       family,
       MIN(CASE WHEN shortage_date = max_date_3m THEN qty ELSE NULL END) AS part_short_3m
 FROM ( SELECT contract,
               part,
               family,
               shortage_date,
               qty,
               MAX(CASE WHEN TRUNC(shortage_date) <= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -3) THEN shortage_date END) OVER (PARTITION BY contract, part, family) AS max_date_3m
          FROM hist_tab
       )
 GROUP BY contract,
          part,
          family;
```

The subquery gives me this result:

```
contract  part    family  shortage_date  qty  max_date_3m
1424F     T69P01  XC      23.11.20       151  19.10.20
1424F     T69P01  XC      12.11.20       190  19.10.20
1424F     T69P01  XC      19.10.20       228  19.10.20
1424F     T69P01  XC      10.10.20       100  19.10.20
```

So now I know the next date less than or equal to Today minus 3 months.

Now I only need the value qty at this date. I assume that it is unique for Contract/Part/Family each date.

The outer query now returns:

```
contract  part    family  part_short_3m
1424F     T69P01  XC      228
```

To Testing:

```
CREATE TABLE hist_tab
( contract VARCHAR2(20),
  part VARCHAR2(20),
  family  VARCHAR2(20),
  shortage_date DATE,
  qty NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO hist_tab VALUES ('1424F', 'T69P01', 'XC', TO_DATE('23.11.2020', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 151);
INSERT INTO hist_tab VALUES ('1424F', 'T69P01', 'XC', TO_DATE('19.10.2020', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 228);
INSERT INTO hist_tab VALUES ('1424F', 'T69P01', 'XC', TO_DATE('12.11.2020', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 190);
INSERT INTO hist_tab VALUES ('1424F', 'T69P01', 'XC', TO_DATE('10.10.2020', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 100);

COMMIT;
```

Comment: If I were needing the sum of all qty's, this would be ideal, but that's not what I'm looking for.  When I take the SUM part from your top select statement out, then I get results of all subsequent dates after that 3m mark.  I'm just needing the next available qty to populate.

Comment: @KassieB Can there be more entries in the mentioned examples as of 10/19/2020? Can you post another example where my query does not work?

Comment: Your query makes no sense. In the subquery, you are grouping by everything, including the date column? Obviously, in each group, the date will be unique - taking an aggregate function over that column, when the column is also in GROUP BY, is meaningless. Downvote from me.

Comment: @mathguy I explained my post further. Have you tried it once? Please show me an example where it does not work. I may have misunderstood the requirement.

Comment: For a simple counter-example, add one more row with the same contract etc., with the date 10.10.2020 and the qty of 100. Your query will now produce the result 328 - the sum of ALL quantities more than (or equal to) three months old. You can't use MAX or MIN either, since that will pick the max or min qty from ALL those older rows, not the "most recent" quantity from those. Other than that, you don't seem to understand my main objection, which is very elementary: it makes no sense to include the date and the quantity in the GROUP BY of the subquery.

Comment: @mathguy You're right. Thank you. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: Yes - the answer is much better now. Note that the LAST aggregate function, which I used in my answer, does the same thing as your updated solution, it just does it all in a single pass.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `last_value()` with a window frame:

```
select contract, family, part,
       last_value(qty) over (order by shortage_date and interval '3' month preceding) as part_short_3m,
       last_value(qty) over (order by shortage_date and interval '6' month preceding) as part_short_6m,
       last_value(qty) over (order by shortage_date and interval '12' month preceding) as part_short_12m
from hist_tab
```

Comment: order by something and interval ... ? What does that even mean? You can fix that (perhaps you meant range between unbounded preceding and interval...) - but that is too much work. The OP doesn't need this as an analytic solution, he only needs one set of values measured from "today".

Comment: Moreover, the last value is measured from the dates stored in the table, not from `sysdate`. This approach can't be saved even if you fix the syntax and you add an over-query to just keep one row out of the analytic output. -1 from me as "not helpful in any way".